# Swiper 8 with Webpack 5: Class not defined

Tags: javascript, webpack, swiper.js, webpack-5

I'm trying to use Swiper 8 with Webpack 5.

In my Webpack config i defined two entry points:

```
module.exports = {
    entry: {
        vendor: './vendor.js',
        frontend: './frontend.js',
    }
    ...
}
```

In the vendor.js I've imported Swiper:

```
import 'swiper/scss';
import Swiper from 'swiper';
```

In the frontend.js I've imported my script files:

```
import './custom.js'
```

No i try to initalize Swiper in my custom.js:

```
const swiper = new Swiper('.swiper', {});
```

Here I get an error message:

***Uncaught ReferenceError: Swiper is not defined***

In my HTML file, I import the vendor.js before the frontend.js file. Theoretically, the Swiper class should be available to me. What am I doing wrong?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/dist/vendor.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/dist/frontend.js"></script>
```

Comment: Can you provide a larger chunk of frontend.js?

Comment: I've only got that single import in the frontend.js - for now. Would you like to see the custom.js?

Comment: I see. I have written an answer. I'm not sure I'm correct, as I have not used webpack for quite a while and I do not have an env to test it, but it very much seems to be the case that the resource is seen by file1 that uses file2, but file2 is not seeing the resource and needs an import as well.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to

```
import Swiper from 'swiper';
```

inside your **custom.js**, because, even though it is properly imported in **frontend.js**, it's not imported in **custom.js** and it is not seen there.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. If I import Swiper in multiple files because I have multiple sliders on my site, won't Swiper be loaded multiple times in the frontend.js file?

Comment: Also, Swiper is not initialized in custom.js until runtime after all. Since Swiper was previously loaded by vendor.js, the class should still be available, right?

Comment: @Jonas The module is evaluated just once. When it was imported for the first time, the same handle is being reused at subsequent import commands. The class is available, but, if it's not imported, it's unusable in the context of custom.js. Imagine the case when there are many classes known as Util, stored in different files. You do not want them to be used by the same name because in different files you imported this class. It would be chaotic. If my answer clarified this, then you may consider accepting it as the correct answer.